# Python : Improve this Reaction-Diffusion algorithm with Numba?

Tags: python, performance, python-imaging-library, numba

Based on the [Coding Challenge #13:  Reaction Diffusion Algorithm in p5.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV9ny785UNc) from Daniel Shiffman, I did the following python script :

```
import numpy as np  
from PIL import Image
from numba import jit 

@jit
def draw(imgA, imgB, nextImgA, nextImgB):
    laplace_kernel = np.array([[ .05, .2, .05],
                               [  .2, -1,  .2],
                               [ .05, .2, .05]])
    for x in range (1, w - 1):
        for y in range (1, h - 1):
            a = imgA[x,y]
            b = imgB[x,y]
            laplace_a = (imgA[x-1 : x+2, y-1 : y+2] * laplace_kernel).sum()
            laplace_b = (imgB[x-1 : x+2, y-1 : y+2] * laplace_kernel).sum()

            nextImgA[x,y] = a + (dA * laplace_a) - (a * b * b) + (feed * (1 - a)) 
            nextImgB[x,y] = b + (dB * laplace_b) + (a * b * b) - ((k + feed) * b) 

    nextImgA = np.clip(nextImgA, 0.0, 1.0) 
    nextImgB = np.clip(nextImgB, 0.0, 1.0) 

    return nextImgA, nextImgB, imgA, imgB

dA   = 1
dB   = 0.5
feed = 0.055
k    = 0.062
w    = 200
h    = 200

imgA     = np.ones ( (w, h) )
imgB     = np.zeros( (w, h) )
nextImgA = np.ones ( (w, h) )
nextImgB = np.zeros( (w, h) )

imgB[100:110, 100:110] = 1.0

for i in range (10000):
    print i
    imgA, imgB, nextImgA, nextImgB = draw( imgA, imgB, nextImgA, nextImgB )


finalImg = np.clip((imgA - imgB) * 255, 0, 255)
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(finalImg))   
img.save("test2.png")
```

It works. After 10000 iterations, here is what I get :

[image]

But it's slow ! I need to wait few minutes to obtain that result. Numba helped a lot to make it quicker but I'm still wondering is there is a way to improve the performance of my script ? Or a way to converge more quickly towards the same pattern ?

Comment: A couple general tips - 1) use `njit` instead of `jit` to force nopython mode, fixing anything that numba can't handle.  2) Use `out=` parameters on numpy functions when possible to reuse temporaries and avoid allocation in the hot loop.

Comment: @chrisb njit isn't defined with Numba 0.35.0 but I can use (at)jit(nopython=True). If I understand you correctly, the fact to force nopython mode allows me too see some errors that need to be corrected if I want I improve the performance, that's correct ?

Comment: Correct - if `nopython=True` errors that means there is something numba is not able to lower to native code

Comment: How slow is slow? for me its 1min43sec. In this case the loops can still be sped up because Numba only has trouble with the lists when defining the kernel (change them to tuples), and `np.clip`. Since the bulk is spend in the loops, changing to nopython mode isnt going to do magic in this case. Still a good idea though, since its certainly possible. Check out the coming stencil decorator in 0.36, that might help in this case, looks very interesting.
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/stencil.html

Comment: @RutgerKassies it slow in the sens that it seems to run a bit slower than the javascript code from Daniel Shiffman which is displayed in real time. I know that js is very well optimised nowadays but that's suprising it can do better than python vectorised. I had the same problem with np.clip and I've an another one with the laplace_kernel : "list(list(float64)): unsupported nested memory-managed object". I didn't understand it very well, looks like its because it is a 2D array, i moved it outside the function, calling it globally, the error disappears but didn't see improvement.

Comment: As I mentioned above, that's because you initialize the array with lists, simply use tuples like: `np.array(((.05,.2,.05),(.2,-1,.2),(.05,.2,.05)))`. Its not going to improve performance. You need to focus on what happens inside the loop for performance gains.

Comment: yes just realized you mentioned it before, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @chrisb and @Rutger Kassies comments, It appears that the most expensive operations was the element wise multiplication between laplace_kernel and the sliding windows. I was able to improve the performance slightly by using a matrix to store the result :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 -S
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np  
from PIL import Image
from numba import jit , njit
from time import time

@njit
def draw(imgA, imgB, nextImgA, nextImgB):
    laplace_kernel = np.array( (( .05, .2, .05),
                                (  .2, -1,  .2),
                                ( .05, .2, .05)) )
    dA   = 1
    dB   = 0.5
    feed = 0.055
    k    = 0.062

    storeMatrix = np.array( ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
                             (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
                             (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) )

    for x in range (1, w - 1):
        for y in range (1, h - 1):
            a = imgA[x,y]
            b = imgB[x,y]
            abb = (a*b*b)

            laplace_a = np.multiply( imgA[x-1 : x+2, y-1 : y+2], laplace_kernel, storeMatrix).sum()       # * dA
            laplace_b = np.multiply( imgB[x-1 : x+2, y-1 : y+2], laplace_kernel, storeMatrix).sum() * 0.5 # * dB

            nextImgA[x,y] = a + ( laplace_a - abb + (feed * (1 - a)) ) 
            nextImgB[x,y] = b + ( laplace_b + abb - ((k + feed) * b) ) 

    return nextImgA, nextImgB, imgA, imgB

w = 200
h = 200

imgA     = np.ones ( (w, h) , dtype=np.float32)
imgB     = np.zeros( (w, h) , dtype=np.float32)
nextImgA = np.ones ( (w, h) , dtype=np.float32)
nextImgB = np.zeros( (w, h) , dtype=np.float32)
imgB[100:110, 100:110] = 1.0

t = time()
for i in range (10000):
    print i
    imgA, imgB, nextImgA, nextImgB = draw( imgA, imgB, nextImgA, nextImgB )
    imgA = np.clip(imgA, 0.0, 1.0) 
    imgB = np.clip(imgB, 0.0, 1.0) 
print "Time Elapsed : " + str(time() - t)

finalImg = np.clip((imgA - imgB) * 255, 0, 255).T
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(finalImg))   
img.save("test2.png")
```

**UPDATE**

Finally, I used PyOpenGL and Pygame in order to use my GPU with a Fragment Shader it is way faster !